# Disabling Submit Button in ASP.NET 3.5 Application with JavaScript breaks BlackBerry submission

Tags: asp.net, javascript, blackberry, postback, blackberry-storm

The following code is being used to disable a Submit button once it has been clicked. This works great on desktop browsers and most BlackBerry mobile browsers.

```
Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:this.disabled=true;" +
    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Submit, null));
```

Unfortunately, when using a BlackBerry Storm clicking the submit button causes the device to just reload the page. If I remove this code the Storm browser submits the page just fine. I need to disable the button when the browser is capable of doing so but do not want to affect browsers that are not JavaScript capable.

I realize I could add the jQuery framework and only attach the event client side, but am trying to look for the simplest fix (read least intrusive) as this is a legacy application. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it this way - I haven't done this in a long time and some of the [HttpCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) API has been tagged as obsolete, but in general you can detect if the browser supports javascript by doing this:

```
    var myBrowserCaps = Request.Browser;
    if (((HttpCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).EcmaScriptVersion.Major > 1)
    {
        // Browser supports javascript
        Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:this.disabled=true;" +
                    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Submit, null));
    }
```

Comment: @Womp that looks good excet rather than `HttpCapabilitiesBase` I used `HttpBrowserCapabilities`. Thank you for the help and sorry for my delay in testing your suggestion. I was AFK for 10 days. ;)